# Finding address of the 'vftable' symbol in an .exe file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, disassembly, vtable, dumpbin

I am trying to find the address (or offset from base address) of the 'vftable' symbol for the class 'Greeter' by statically analyzing an executable file. While analyzing it dynamically in Visual Studio by adding a breakpoint and disassembling the constructor of the 'Greeter' class, I was able to find the address of the symbol.

```
00007FF76A891951  lea         rcx,[Greeter::`vftable' (07FF76A89ACE0h)]  
00007FF76A891958  mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx
```

But this is it's runtime address. I need to find a way to figure out the offset by maybe using a tool like 'dumpbin' or something similar. I know I can figure out the offset by using the address above, but I need a way to automate this, so it will have to be through a tool.

I tried using 'dumpbin' on the exe to disassemble it and find the same instructions of the Greeter class:

```
0000000140011951: 48 8D 0D 88 93 00  lea         rcx,[??_7Greeter@@6B@]
0000000140011958: 48 89 08           mov         qword ptr [rax],rcx
```

So, I set out to try to find references to this symbol `??_7Greeter@@6B@`

I tried using 'dumpbin' with the following command:

```
dumpbin /all ConsoleApplication.obj > cout
```

I got the following relevant output:

```
        Section length   18, #relocs    3, #linenums    0, checksum        0, selection    6 (pick largest)
    Relocation CRC BDB82F45
134 00000008 SECT43 notype       External     | ??_7Greeter@@6B@ (const Greeter::`vftable')
135 00000000 SECT44 notype       Static       | .rdata
```

I also got this output:

```
SECTION HEADER #43
  .rdata name
       0 physical address
       0 virtual address
      18 size of raw data
    DA3B file pointer to raw data (0000DA3B to 0000DA52)
    DA53 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       3 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40401040 flags
         Initialized Data
         COMDAT; sym= "const Greeter::`vftable'" (??_7Greeter@@6B@)
         8 byte align
         Read Only

RAW DATA #43
  00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  00000010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

RELOCATIONS #43
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000000  ADDR64            00000000 00000000       14C  ??_R4Greeter@@6B@ (const Greeter::`RTTI Complete Object Locator')
 00000008  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        8C  ?sayHello@Greeter@@UEAAX_J00@Z (public: virtual void __cdecl Greeter::sayHello(__int64,__int64,__int64))
 00000010  ADDR64            00000000 00000000        8D  ?initUser@Greeter@@UEAAXXZ (public: virtual void __cdecl Greeter::initUser(void))
```

Does anybody have any idea how I would go about finding the offset of this symbol? Is there a specific 'dumpbin' option that I need to use to print offset of symbols that are mentioned in the disassembly?